# Whats the difference between @if and @can in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, conditional-statements

Were making a project with different users. I noticed that I can use `@if` to prevent specific user from a specific function but I can also use `@can`. Can someone tell me what are thier differences. I did not register any policies in `AuthServiceProvider` but I can still use `@can` method. I'm just referring to the type of user.  I'll show you some code.

Can

```
   @can($global_user->role != 0)
            <li class="{{ $mnuname == 'Issue' ? 'active' : '' }}">
              <a href="{{ route('admin.issues') }}" onclick="return LoadingOverlay();">
                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                <span>Issue Tracker</span>
              </a>
            </li>
  @endcan
```

If

```
   @if($global_user->role != 0)

        <li class="{{ $mnuname == 'Student' ? 'active' : '' }}">
          <a href="{{ route('admin.students') }}" onclick="return LoadingOverlay();">
            <i class="fa fa-child"></i>
            <span>Students</span>
          </a>
        </li>
@endif
```

Edit: Can I also use `@can` inside `@if` statements like this?

```
    @if($global_user->role != 0)
        <li class="treeview
            {{ $mnuname == 'New Issue' ? 'active' : '' }}
            {{ $mnuname == 'Issue' ? 'active' : '' }}
            ">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-bug"></i> <span>System Issues</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">

            <li class="{{ $mnuname == 'New Issue' ? 'active' : '' }}">
              <a href="{{ route('admin.issues.create') }}" onclick="return LoadingOverlay();">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                <span>Report an Issue</span>
              </a>
            </li>


            @can($global_user->role != 3)
            <li class="{{ $mnuname == 'Issue' ? 'active' : '' }}">
              <a href="{{ route('admin.issues') }}" onclick="return LoadingOverlay();">
                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                <span>Issue Tracker</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            @endcan


          </ul>
        </li>
        @endif
```

Comment: No one wants to answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@if` directive is use for rendering conditional portion in blade template.
and `@can` directive is use for `authorize` a user based on the `Gate` and `Policy` in laravel.

> @if directive example

```
@if($global_user->role == admin)

 //only to shows this portion to admin user
@endif
```

> @can directive example

```
@can($global_user->role == admin)

 //here this portion verify by Gate and policy and middleware only ADMIN role to perform on this portion.
@endcan
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation sir!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm a few(probably one too many) beers in but I'll take a stab at it:

The [@can](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-blade-templates) helpers are really designed for [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#creating-policies). While the intent is to return a boolean value to provide simplistic guard functionality, they aid in providing readability when creating policies so that the complex guard functionality can remain abstract to the view and be reusable across multiple blade views in addition to controller methods using the `authorize` api.

The `@if` directive is just that, a simple blade style syntax `if` conditional to be utilized in any blade view.

Comment: Ohh. I see. Thanks for it sir!